# Influxdb high CPU usage jumping to 80 %?

Tags: influxdb

I am relatively new to time series db world . I am running a Influxdb 1.8.x as a docker container, and I have configured the influxdb.conf file as a default config. Currently I am facing a issue of high CPU usage by influxdb, the CPU jumps to 80 to 90% and creating a problem for other process running on same machine.
I have tried a solution given here ->> [Influx high CPU issue](https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb/issues/19543) but unfortunately It did not work? I am unable to understand the reason behind the issue and also struggling to get support in terms of documentation or community help.
What I have tried so far:

1. updated the monitor section of influxdb.conf file like this ->> [monitor DB](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.8/administration/config/#monitoring-settings)
2. Checked the series cardinality `SHOW SERIES CARDINALITY` and it looks well within limits--9400(I am also not sure about the ideal number for high cardinality red flag)

I am looking for an approach, which will help me understand this problem the root cause?

Please let me know if you need any further information on same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After reading about Influxdb debug and CPU profiling [HTTP API influxdb](https://www.alibabacloud.com/help/doc-detail/113115.htm) I was able to pin-down the issue, the problem was in the way I was making the query, my query involved more complex functions and also `GROUP BAY` tag.I also tried query analysis using `EXPLAIN ANALYZE (query)` command to check how much time a query is taking to execute. I resolved that and noticed a huge Improvement in CPU load.
Basically I can suggest the following:

1. Run the CPU profile analysis using influxdb HTTP API with the command `curl -o <file name> http://localhost:8086/debug/pprof/all?cpu=true e` and collect result.
2. Visualize the result using tool like [Pprof tool](https://github.com/google/pprof?spm=a2c63.p38356.879954.5.7aff6056WkxYmC) and find the problem
3. Also one can run basic commands like `SHOW SERIES CARDINALITY` and `EXPLAIN ANALYZE <query>` to understand the execution of the query
4. Before designing any schema and Influx client check the hardware recommendation ->> [Hardware sizing guidelines](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.8/guides/hardware_sizing/)